# view multi-core or mlti-cpu utlization on linux

Tags: linux, multicore

I have a program running on Linux and I need to determine how it is utilizing all the CPUs/cores. Is there any program for viewing this information?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When runnging the `top` command, press `f` then `j` to display the P column (last CPU used by process), in addition to the `1` command in top, you should view some multi core occupation informations :)

Answer (score 45):

Run the '*top*' command and press '*1*' to see the individual cores.

Comment: great! But how can I save the command result into a file periodically by running a script? You know, you can't press a key in a script. Is there any 'top' option available to turn on this feature?

Comment: @snowfox: you can press W (capitalized) when running `top` to save the current state.

Answer (score 18):

`htop` shows you the cpu usage of each core in a graphical manner (ncurses).

Answer (score 4):

mpstat -P ALL 5 5 >>your.file

You may need to parse this to use it for a presentation, or sum it  But read the man page as mpstat has some useful options.

Answer (score 4):

Run the 'top' command and press '1' to see the individual core is the best way to see
the cpu cores usage ..
another option is run cmd-  cat /proc/stat
to see the  cpu cores usage