# cpu utilization of android app

Tags: android, linux

I am trying to write a small code that would dump out the CPU utilization (% of cpu used in last 10 secs and dump that every 10 seconds) of my android app.

Now assuming there are 2 or 4 cores in the phone. How to dump effectively the % cpu utilized by the app. I have googled some samples of top command but I am not sure how to use the figures of top command to display cpu utilization across multicore and in last 10 secs.

I have added the following code: but I am always getting null in the `buf. exec` returns valid result with `ls` command but not with `top`. Do i need to get some permission in mainfest to execute top command...

```
    String str = new String();
    str = "top -l1";
    Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
    BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    /* Skip 6 lines */
    int count = 0;
    char[] buf= new char[10240];
     bri.read(buf);
     Log.e("TEST", new String(buf));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `top`, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899227/view-multi-core-or-mlti-cpu-utlization-on-linux) seems to suggest that there is a way to collect data from individual cores.

In any case, I would suggest you use the [Dumpsys tool](http://source.android.com/tech/input/dumpsys.html) instead, which is much more interesting, since it can provide you with CPU utilization regardless of the number of cores. For example, the command:

```
adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo
```

will give output of the form:

```
Load: 0.08 / 0.4 / 0.64
CPU usage from 42816ms to 34683ms ago:
system_server: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor
kdebuglog.sh: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 160 minor
tiwlan_wq: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
usb_mass_storag: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
pvr_workqueue: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
+sleep: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
+sleep: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
TOTAL: 6% = 1% user + 3% kernel + 0% irq
```

Check out this SO answer for more details on how to use Dumpsys: [What's the Android ADB shell "dumpsys" tool and what are its benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool)

Comment: I need per process basis and all at one time. I am writing this diagnostic tool to dump out how my process behaves over time.

Comment: apparantly the permission android.permission.DUMP is required which is not allowed as per the project requirement I am working with

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who reached this question to solve this problem, I am posting my solution on how to get the value of cpu usage from "top" command

```
private String getCpuUsage()
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String cpuUsageValue = "";

        Process p = null;
        try {

            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "top -n 1 | grep " + appProcessName }); //appProcessName is com.example.app

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        int i =0;
        String line = "";
        try {

            line = reader.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //while(line != null)
        if(line != null)
        {

            //11203  0   0% S    13 901560K  43528K  fg u0_a141  com.example.app

            String lineOuput[] = line.split(" ");
            cpuUsageValue = lineOuput[5].trim();
            //[19472, , 0, , , 0%, S, , , , 15, 904664K, , 44148K, , fg, u0_a141, , com.example.app]

            Log.i(TAG, "cpu usage value : " + cpuUsageValue);

            list.add(line);
            try {
                line = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "command line is null");

        }

        return cpuUsageValue;


    }
```